# display all time appointments and reserve

Tags: php, mysql

My system for appointments has some managers(Ex. doctor), and I intend for all appointment times to display in a table so appointments are filled or empty with the name of the user
Create a table for times appointments :

```
+-----------+-----------+
| id         | time 
+-----------+------------
| 1         | 10:00     |
| 2         | 10:30     |
| 3         | 11:00     |
| 4         | 11:30     |
| 5         | 12:00     |
| 6         | 12:30     |
| 7         | 13:00     |
| 8         | 13:30     |
| 9         | 14:00     |
+-----------+-----------+
```

manager  table

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| id         | name       | phone     |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1         | alex        | 123456    |
| 2         | dany        | 123456    |
```

user table :

```
+----+------+-------+-----------+
| id | manager_id | name | phone |
+----+------------+------+-----------+
| 1  | 1       |   John  | 123456   |
| 2  | 1       |   Sara  | 123456   |
| 3  | 2       |   lorem | 123456   |
+----+------+-------+-----------+
```

and order table(for appointments)

```
+----+------+-------+------------------+-----------+
| id | manager_id | userid  | reserveid| datereserve
+----+------------+------+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1       |   1        | 1        |2016/12/28
| 2  | 1       |   2        | 2        |2016/12/28
| 3  | 2       |   3        | 3        |2016/12/28
+----+------+-------+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Now I want to display reserved time in a table in which appointments filled or empty with the name of the user
like :
[Similar this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dgeW.png)

I Joined all of tables in query but can't display similar photo and fetch data:(
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  m.name,
  a.time,
  u.phone,
  u.name <- if u.name or u.phone is NULL, then appointment is free now
FROM manager as m
CROSS JOIN appointments as a
LEFT JOIN order as o ON o.manager_id = m.id AND o.appointmentsid = a.id 
LEFT JOIN user as u ON u.id =  o.userid

#for some doctor
WHERE m.id = DoctorID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another table

```
create table status(id int, name varchar(50));
```

and insert values (1, "reserved"), (2, "free").

```
select t.time, s.name, m.name, u.name, u.phone 
from time t left join status s on t.id = s.id 
left join order o on o.appointmentsid = t.id 
left join manager m on o.manager_id = m.id 
left join users u on o.userid = u.id;
```